# Why importing the Vue.js source works, but not the module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-2

The following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        Greeting below: 
        <div id="time">
            {{greetings}}
        </div>
        <script src='bundle.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

together with the `entry.js` file

```
// either the import or the require work
Vue = require('./vue.js')
//import Vue from './vue.js'
new Vue({
    el: "#time",
    data: {
        greetings: "hello world"
    }
})
```

and the `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

works fine (`vue.js` is locally downloaded from the site or a CDN).

I then tried to use the `vue` module installed via `npm install vue --save-dev` by changing `entry.js` to

```
import Vue from 'vue'
new Vue({
    el: "#time",
    data: {
        greetings: "hello world"
    }
})
```

This version does not work anymore: the whole `<div>` is not rendered (only `Greeting below` is displayed).

**What should be done so that Vue.js can be used with webpack?**

The Vue documentation mentions webpack a few times, but only in the context of components or production builds.

Comment: Native imports are now supported in recent browser versions. So `webpack` and other `node`/`npm` baggage may no longer be necessary for simple apps: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose the problem it's a good idea to look for any errors, whether it's from the build tool on the command line or in the devtools in the browser. If you open the devtools console you'll see the following warning from Vue:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

Vue has a two different builds, [Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only). If you have templates in the DOM, they need to be compiled in order to use them. By default Vue contains only the runtime, because its more light-weight and usually the templates are already pre-compiled to JavaScript at build time.

To also include the compiler you need to import `vue/dist/vue.esm`:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
```

This is the same version as the one from the CDN, except that it uses ES modules, which webpack will handle and you should prefer it over `vue/dist/vue.js`, which is exactly the one from the CDN.

Alternatively you can use webpacks [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to define an alias, so when you import `vue` it will import `vue/dist/vue.esm` instead.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
}
```

To be able to use the runtime-only build, you can use [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with a `.vue` file. For that you will have to configure [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader), which will pre-compile the templates at build time.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer - but I do not use components. As you can see in the question, this is just a basic Vue.js app to learn integration with Vue.js. In that context: what is wrong with using `import Vue from 'vue'
`?

Comment: I'm aware that you're not using any components. But you are using a template in the DOM: `<div id="time">{{greetings}}</div>` and that requires the template compiler, which is not in the regular import (`vue`), but it is available in `vue/dist/vue.esm.js` in the npm package. The source you downloaded does contain the template compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can import the compiled (dist) version of vue instead.

`import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'`

Comment: Isn't the module specifier supposed to be prefaced with './' or whatnot?

Comment: The assumption in the example is that you are importing it from the `node_modules` folder.